# Turn off close Facebook friend notification

Tags: facebook

Many people added me as a close friend and they receive updates about my activities on Facebook. I do not want to show them via notification what I post or what I like.

How to turn these notifications off?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot stop them, it is their profile not yours.

Your only options are:

- Post less
- Message them and tell them to remove you from their close friends
- Change your privacy options on your posts to me or a restricted friend subset

Answer (score 1):

You can tell your friends how to turn off close friend notifications by doing the following:

- Click `Close Friends` in the left navigation of Facebook's home page

  - You'll see the below with Close Friends highlighted

[image: Close Friends Active Page]

- In the upper right (below the Facebook header) you'll see the following with a checkmark:

[image]

- Click `Notifications`

[image]

- Select `Off`

  - You'll see a strike through icon now

[image]