# Avoid friends from getting my notifications

Tags: facebook, notifications, friends

I want that even if my friends have activated "Get notifications" for me, stop them from getting my notifications because I don't want my friends from seeing my likes, comments and so.

I have seen [How do I stop friends from getting notifications about what I do on Facebook?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/28827/how-do-i-stop-friends-from-getting-notifications-about-what-i-do-on-facebook) and my question is right that.

But unfortunately it has been marked as duplicate with a totally different question ([Turn off close Facebook friend notification](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/28763/turn-off-close-facebook-friend-notification)) while they differ.

Comment: @phwd As I clearly stated, it's NOT really a duplicate of the question. There are obvious differences.

Comment: There are no differences other than close friends vs just friends. It's the same conclusion. Your friends can control their subscription to you, the only thing you can do is limit your privacy, which is exactly what the answer below and the answer in the duplicate describes.

Comment: I don't know why this question is marked as duplicate. The linked question is clearly different to the question asked here. This question asks "How to hide *my* notification from friends". The linked question asks "How to turn off notification from *close friends*". The difference is not even subtle... it is very obvious!

Comment: I have changed the duplicate target in response to a flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think a normal Facebook user would want to get notified when his "friend" does a like or comments.Also I don't think if it's possible to hide your activities coming up on news ticker on the sidebar.

Even if you comment on a mutual friend's photo and if the other friend is following that post, he'll receive notificationl.

The best way to entirely hide from those friends is to un friend or may be block them on facebook.